# getting the biggest sample frequency supported from ALSA

Tags: c, linux, alsa

I was wondering if  there is a ALSA function that can tell which sample frequencies are supported by the recording using ALSA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be the [snd_pcm_hw_params_get_rate_max](http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/group___p_c_m___h_w___params.html#ga6770c2b988c8dc91eb51893cc145aa2c) function.

For an example, see [hw_params.c](http://download.atmark-techno.com/misc/demos/usb-audio-a500-howto/hw_params.c).